# Correct way to build "live" directory structure after maven build?

Tags: java, linux, bash, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a multi module maven project which looks something like:

- main

  - component_one

    - subcomponent_bob
    - subcomponent_mike
    - subcomponent_joe
  - component_one_aggregate
  - component_two

    - subcomponent_tim
    - subcomponent_lary
  - component_two_aggregate

The aggregate projects create parent jars for each of the components containing all of their subcomponents.

I have a pom in each directory, and it all deploys to a local repository. Everything works great!

Except that I would like to have the directory strucuture that "ties it all together" be created as well, something like:

- main

  - deploy

    - server

      - lib

        - component_one.jar
      - .. other stuff, start scripts, configs, etc
    - client

      - lib

        - component_two.jar
      - ... other stuff, start scripts, etc

I'm looking for the "right" way to do this.

I've figured out a variety of hacky ways to do this involving post deploy goals, antrun, etc. I simply can't find evidence for this being possible in a "correct" way, is this simply outside the scope of maven?

I've been thinking of creating a Makefile to wrap maven and some bash scripts to move the files around post maven deploy, but I still feel like this isn't a great way of doing it either.

What am I misisng?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create such a structure via the [Maven-Assembly-Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

Comment: Exactly what I needed, in fact was already using it to create some of my more complex jars. Just didn't realize it could do directories!